# Determine which w3wp.exe process belongs to which App Pool in Windows 7 / IIS7.5?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-7, windows-7, .net-2.0

I've recently upgraded my development machine from Windows XP to Windows 7.  How can I tell which w3wp.exe process belongs to which App Pool on a desktop running Windows 7?

- [On a server running IIS6, you can run **c:\windows\system32\cscript iisapp.vbs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658749/how-can-i-determine-which-w3wp-exe-process-belongs-to-which-web-site)
- [On a Windows 2008 Server running IIS7 you can run **appcmd list wp**](https://web.archive.org/web/20200105145326/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/WorldofTray/archive/2009/11/05/how-to-determine-which-application-pool-w3wp.exe-belongs-to-on-again.aspx)

But what about on my desktop?

Comment: [Find Process Id of an IIS Site by Site Name](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/find-process-id-of-an-iis-site-by-site-name/)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you open IIS Manager, go to the root node in the tree on the left that represents your computer (should be labeled as your computer name).

In the Features View to the right, you'll see a section called **IIS**. Under that you'll see `Worker Processes`. Select that and it should show you all running worker processes and some basic info, including ProcessId.

You can correlate that ProcessId to the matching process in the Processes tab in Task Manager (showing processes from all users, and including the ProcessId column in the results).

Comment: Awesome, not need for roulette debugging.

Answer (score 29):

You can also go into Task Manager and add the **PID** and **Command Line** columns to see the information you need.

[image]

The blacked out content contains the names of the individual processes.

I find this workflow just slightly less cumbersome than having to navigate away from what I may be looking at in IIS just to see this information (*to then have to navigate right back to where I was*).

Comment: I like this. With keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl-Shift-Escape, "w3") this is a lot quicker than firing up IIS manager and using several mouse clicks here and there to make it give you the information. And it refreshes automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but here is a way to enumerate the app pool and process IDs using C# code.

```
void Main()
{
    using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
    {
        foreach (var appPool in serverManager.ApplicationPools)
        {
            string.Format("App pool name = {0}", appPool.Name).Dump();

            foreach (var workerProcess in appPool.WorkerProcesses)
            {
                string.Format("Process id = {0}", workerProcess.ProcessId).Dump();
            }
        }

        "Done".Dump();
    }
}
```

Make sure you reference **Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll** in %WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv.

If you don't have [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), replace the dumps with `Console.WriteLine`(s)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which I prefer "task manager" version.

#### Option A - Using task manager,

1. Open Task Manager
2. Add *"command line"* column as shown in the images.

   [image]
   [image]

#### Option B - Using PowerShell

1. Run the follow commands

   ```
   cd C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\
   .\appcmd list wp
   ```

   [image]